# Content Script Matches

Tags: html, content-script, manifest.json

So while setting up my Content Scripts in my

> .manifest

file, however, I can't seem to figure out how to set google as a match..
I have done it with google.com and .co.nz and that works but only if I make myself go to the .com site and I am in NZ so I auto go to .co.nz, But I want it to work on all pages that have https://google, I've tried these so far but none of them work..

> "matches": ["https://www.google*"]
>
> "matches": ["https://www.google/*"]
>
> "matches": ["https://www.google.*"]
>
> "matches": ["https://www.google.co/*"]
>
> "matches": ["https://www.google.*"]
>
> "matches": ["https://www.google.co*"]

And maybe a few others Idk

Does anyone have the answer?

I have no problem with Netflix or youtube since they both have .com by default no matter where I am..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it works on google domains.
So it doesn't work on www.google.com, maps.google.com, etc...

I think.